# navigation in a android app with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY & startActivityForResult

Tags: android

I have a problem with navigation in an android app with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` and `startActivityForResult`.

Here is an example:

I have page A and page B. I go from A to B with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`. Then I take a picture with `startActivityForResult`.

The problem is, now I get back to page A, but I want to get back to page B.

When I remove the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` I have page B in the history which I don't want to have.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Please can your explain witch navigation you aim to get. You are just showing two scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the history, but when you come back to your page B, just call this.finish().
This activity will end.
You will probably see your page B for a second (could be depend on your code, to test).

Hope this solution could help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are moving from

**1.** Page A -> Page B with flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`

**2.** You start another activity from Page B with `startActivityForResult`

Now when you come back no Page B found bcoz of the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`.

Now remove the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` from `Page B` activty and when you get the callback in `onActivityResult()` of your `Page B`, `finish()` the `page B` activity.

Answer (score 0):

It's truly depend on your code.

Hope you had try by this way.

Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeOtherClass.class);

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY); // do not keep this intent in history.

startActivity(intent);

Try it or upload your code so i can see in detail.